# $user value in shell script is not fetching the proper value

Tags: shell

I am trying to connect to the sqlplus session from a unix session, dynamically, using the value $user.

Below are the lines in my shell script

```
c=`echo $user | cut -c -2`"OPR"`echo $user | cut -c 6-`
echo $c
sqlplus -s `echo $c`/`echo $c`@$OPERATIONAL_DB_NAME @dbl.sql $x $y
```

If I run the above two commands separately in the `unix` prompt, it is working fine, but when I put these two lines in a .sh script and run, then the whole first command doesn't work properly.
i.e. when I run the first command in Unix prompt, the value of `C=itOPR173`.

But, when I run the .sh script file, then the value of `c=OPR`.

Because of this error, the `sqlplus` session is not getting connected.

Comment: Make sure the case of your parameters are the same.

Comment: Have you set $user yourself?  The system variable is $USER.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried with $USER and it worked, but when i directly gave c=`echo $user | cut -c -2`"OPR"`echo $user | cut -c 6-` in the unix prompt, it took the proper value of the logged in user name, so I didn't think about that....